# Running .NET Core 2.0 API from the command line

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core, connection-string

When I run a REST API written in .NET Core 2.0 that uses HttpSys from within Visual Studio 2017, I get the following output:

> Exe path : C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe Directory : C:\Program
> Files\dotnet Connection string :
> Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=MyApp;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true
> Hosting environment: Development Content root path:
> C:\Users\Torsten\source\repos\MyApp\MyApp Now listening
> on: http://*:5000 Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

When I run the same application from the command line with

```
dotnet myapp
```

I get this output:

> dotnet MyApp.dll Exe path : C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe Directory : C:\Program Files\dotnet Connection
> string :  info:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
> User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\Torsten\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key
> repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt  keys at rest.
> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
> connectionString

Why is the connection string not recognized when started from the command line?

The connection string is defined in appsettings.json as:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": { "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MyApp;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" },
```

And the Startup.cs reads:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var pathToExe = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
        Console.WriteLine("Exe path : " + pathToExe);
        Console.WriteLine("Directory : " + Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe));
        Console.WriteLine("Command line arguments :" + String.Join(", ",Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()));
        Console.WriteLine("Connection string : " + Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]);
        services.AddDbContext<MyAppContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]));
        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

Comment: You'd have to ask whatever is creating `Configuration`, because that's the one that's not initializing properly. Dependency injection is fun!

Comment: Are you running the command from the application's directory? configuration loading defaults to the current working directory..

Comment: Yes. I am running it from the application directory.

Comment: I also tried with `Start-process -FilePath dotnet.exe MyApp.dll -workingdirectory . ` Same result.

Comment: That looks like PowerShell, though. The current location in PowerShell is not the same as the current directory in Windows. Try an `[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = pwd` first.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert: Thank you. I tried that, but it does not solve the problem. I tried it also with cmd.exe with Administrator privileges. Still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the ConnectionString could not be read, is, that the appsettings.json does not get copied to the output directory by default. Only if you configure *Copy to Output Directory* as *Copy if newer* or *Copy always* does it get copied to the output directory.
You can tell the difference by looking at the `env.ContentRootPath` in the `Configure` method.

When started from within Visual Studio, ContentRootPath is the project directory.

> C:\Users\Somebody\source\repos\MyApp\MyApp

When started from the command line, ContentRootPath is the output directory.

> C:\Users\Somebody\source\repos\MyApp\MyApp\bin\debug\netcoreapp2.0

Answer (score 0):

Rerun, from the project folder, the dotnet command with -v switch to see results. If you are seeing references to .**..\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools.dotnet\1.0.0..** the problem is with CLIToolReference which must be updated.

I had the same issue when I was migrating a project from an older version of asp.net core. After migration the DotNetCliToolReference is not automatically updated.
Update the **yourproject.csproj** file to use the **2.0.0** version of the CLI as shown in the snippet bellow:

```
<ItemGroup>

        ...
          <DotNetCliToolReference 
               Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" 
               Version="2.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Also check your C:\Users\Torsten\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys\....xml file to reference Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, Version=2.0.0.0. If you are in development envirionment, after you fixed your csproj file, you may delete the file, and it will be recreated with right referenced version

Comment: I did not migrate. I started with DotNet Core 2.0. Everything points to 2.0.0 Versions. Thank you for suggesting it.

Comment: Which output are you obtaining if you run the dotnet in verbose mode (with -v option)?

Comment: I cannot call dotnet with the -v option. If I call `dotnet -v MyApp.dll`, it lists all the possible command line switches. If I call `dotnet MyApp.dll -v`, I get an exception `Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: The short switch '-v' is not defined in the switch mappings.`

Comment: You may run dotnet with sdk-options or runtime-options. Verbose mode is not a choice in runtime-options. Sdk-options are run, build etc. I'm sorry for not being too explicit, but I was trying to say dotnet run -v diag